# Xcode Swift 4.2 migration with multiple targets

Tags: swift, xcode, migration

I have multiple targets for my project. After updating Xcode, I chose to perform the Swift migration to the latest version. I successfully performed the migration, but it turned out to be for only one target.

So I followed the instructions at the bottom of this migration guide: https://swift.org/migration-guide-swift4

> If you have multiple schemes in your project that cover different targets, you will only get notified that you need to migrate one of them. You will need to manually select the new scheme, then run Edit -> Convert -> To Current Swift Syntax to migrate the remaining schemes.

However, I'm getting an error:

[image]

However, since I performed the migration and the targets share files, I now have tons of errors that prevent me from being able to successfully build.

I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem but the [migration guide](https://swift.org/migration-guide-swift4.2/) actually mentions about another solution to this problem.

> If you have multiple schemes in your project that cover different targets, you will only get notified that you need to migrate one of them. You will need to manually select the new scheme, then run Edit -> Convert -> To Current Swift Syntax to migrate the remaining schemes. **Or you can create a scheme that includes all the targets from your project, and have it selected before running the migration assistant.**

So go ahead and create a new scheme. It will only let you add a single target when creating it. Then edit that new scheme and add the rest of the targets you have. Use the migration tool to migrate all the targets at the same time. When it's done delete the scheme you created.

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing that out. It sounds like I'll have to revert my current migration, though, since I'm not able to run the migration assistant, right? Or does changing the scheme somehow ignore the fact that one target will build while the other fails? I've continued working on the development branch for the target that I migrated, figuring I'll be able to sort the other target out later. Sounds like I need to check out the commit before I migrated, migrate with a scheme that builds all targets, then rebase the other work on top. If I'm mistaken and overcomplicating this, tell me :)

Comment: Yes, you probably need to use the commit before the migration because for the migration assistant to work, you shouldn't have any build errors on any of your targets of the selected scheme.